# How to find the position of elements in ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

My code match the character entered by user with ArrayList having characters, and display results. I used loop and IF statement to print different results for matched characters and unmatched characters. I used Array.Contains() method to compare the user input with ArrayList elements. I am trying to print the position of the element in the ArrayList when matched.

For example: ArrayList has: [a, b, c, d] and the positions (0 for a, 1 for b, 2 for c and 3 for d). How can I do it programatically to print the position of the element matched?

Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<Character> charsList = new ArrayList<Character>();

for (int i = 0; i < wordsList[0].length(); i++) {
    charsList.add(wordsList[0].charAt(i));
}

for (int i = 0; i < wordsList[0].length(); i++) {
    inputValue = input.next().charAt(0);
    if (charsList.contains(inputValue)) {
        System.out.println("Matched!");  
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not Matched!");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the indexOf method.

```
System.out.println(charList.indexOf(inputValue));
```

Comment: Be careful this only returns the first occurrence or -1 if not exists. If your list contains duplicates you can create new sublists or iterate over the first occurrence to the last index.

Comment: It appears that the OP is using the charList as a reference set, which sounds to be a unique set.